# CME datamine sample files in python

Tags: python, pandas, fix-protocol

I have some sample market data from CME DataMine.  The files look like the following

```
'1128=9\x019=156\x0135=X\x0149=CME\x0134=431875\x0152=20130715053428544\x0175=20130715\x01268=1\x01279=1\x0122=8\x0148=19590\x0183=1491\x01107=ZCN4-ZCU4\x01269=0\x01270=0.75\x01271=7\x01273=53428000\x01336=2\x01346=3\x011023=3\x0110=233\x01'\n
'1128=9\x019=104\x0135=f\x0149=CME\x0134=6613\x0152=20130714180206034\x0122=8\x0148=164576\x0175=20130715\x01107=ZC:BF H4-K4-N4\x01332=159\x01333=-161\x0110=138\x01'\n
'1128=9\x019=1634\x0135=X\x0149=CME\x0134=3177179\x0152=20130715181451830\x0175=20130715\x01268=16\x01279=1\x0122=8\x0148=1647\x0183=180151\x01107=ZC:BF U3-Z3-H4\x01269=1\x01270=45\x01271=195\x01273=181451000\x01276=K\x01336=2\x011023=2\x01279=1\x0122=8\x0148=21907\x0183=118087\x01107=ZCU3-ZCH4\x01269=1\x01270=21\x01271=3\x01273=181451000\x01276=K\x01336=2\x011023=1\x01279=1\x0122=8\x0148=21907\x0183=118088\x01107=ZCU3-ZCH4\x01269=1\x01270=21.25\x01271=10\x01273=181451000\x01276=K\x01336=2\x011023=2\x01279=1\x0122=8\x0148=504398\x0183=29594\x01107=ZCU3-ZCH5\x01269=1\x01270=11.25\x01271=3\x01273=181451000\x01276=K\x01336=2\x011023=1\x01279=1\x0122=8\x0148=504398\x0183=29595\x01107=ZCU3-ZCH5\x01269=1\x01270=11.5\x01271=2\x01273=181451000\x01276=K\x01336=2\x011023=2\x01279=1\x0122=8\x0148=21970\x0183=50008\x01107=ZCU3-ZCK4\x01269=1\x01270=13.5\x01271=3\x01273=181451000\x01276=K\x01336=2\x011023=1\x01279=1\x0122=8\x0148=21970\x0183=50009\x01107=ZCU3-ZCK4\x01269=1\x01270=13.75\x01271=8\x01273=181451000\x01276=K\x01336=2\x011023=2\x01279=1\x0122=8\x0148=558644\x0183=48554\x01107=ZCU3-ZCN4\x01269=1\x01270=7\x01271=3\x01273=181451000\x01276=K\x01336=2\x011023=1\x01279=1\x0122=8\x0148=558644\x0183=48555\x01107=ZCU3-ZCN4\x01269=1\x01270=7.25\x01271=8\x01273=181451000\x01276=K\x01336=2\x011023=2\x01279=1\x0122=8\x0148=22098\x0183=52504\x01107=ZCU3-ZCU4\x01269=1\x01270=15.25\x01271=3\x01273=181451000\x01276=K\x01336=2\x011023=1\x01279=1\x0122=8\x0148=22098\x0183=52505\x01107=ZCU3-ZCU4\x01269=1\x01270=15.5\x01271=1\x01273=181451000\x01276=K\x01336=2\x011023=2\x01279=0\x0122=8\x0148=504409\x0183=16282\x01107=ZCU3-ZCU5\x01269=1\x01270=25.25\x01271=1\x01273=181451000\x01276=K\x01336=2\x011023=2\x01279=1\x0122=8\x0148=588275\x0183=265779\x01107=ZCU3-ZCZ3\x01269=1\x01270=33\x01271=3\x01273=181451000\x01276=K\x01336=2\x011023=1\x01279=1\x0122=8\x0148=588275\x0183=265780\x01107=ZCU3-ZCZ3\x01269=1\x01270=33.25\x01271=20\x01273=181451000\x01276=K\x01336=2\x011023=2\x01279=0\x0122=8\x0148=519645\x0183=32899\x01107=ZCU3-ZCZ4\x01269=1\x01270=9.75\x01271=1\x01273=181451000\x01276=K\x01336=2\x011023=2\x01279=0\x0122=8\x0148=19282\x0183=20689\x01107=ZCU3-ZCZ5\x01269=1\x01270=29.75\x01271=1\x01273=181451000\x01276=K\x01336=2\x011023=2\x0110=007\x01'\n
```

That is, in each row, fields are separated by the \x01 character, and each field contains entries in the form tag=value.

The tags and values correspond to those specified in the FIXML specs: https://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/5.0.SP2/fields_by_tag.html

I would like to parse this file into a Pandas DataFrame where the column names are the tag names, the rows are the rows in the data file and the values are parsed values (so for example, Column 1 will be AppVerId, and row 1, column 1 will be: FIX50SP2).

How can I do this using pandas?

I have tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df  = pd.read_table('data/corn/MDFF_CBT_20130714-20130715_7813_0',delimiter='\x01',header=None)
```

but get the following error:

> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 22 fields in
>   line 3, saw 202

I am guessing this has to do with the fact that not all rows have the same number of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main problem is in third column tag are duplicated. So need `defaultdict` for store:

```
from collections import defaultdict

rows = []
with open("CME.dat") as f:
    for line in f:
        row_dict = defaultdict(list)
        # split each line
        for element in line.split('\\x01'):
            try:
                tag, val = element.split('=')
                row_dict[tag].append(val)
            except:
                pass
        rows.append(row_dict)
#print (rows)
```

Then create `DataFrame` but for scalar from lists first need replace `NaN`s to `[]`, remove `'` from columns names. Last use list comprehension with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and if necessary fill `NaN`s per rows add [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(rows).applymap(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, list) else [])

df.columns = df.columns.str.strip("'")
df = (pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df[x].values.tolist()) for x in df], keys=df.columns, axis=1)
       .stack()
       .groupby(level=0)
       .ffill()
       .reset_index(drop=True))
```

---

```
print (df)

   1128   10  1023             107 22   268   269    270   271        273  \
0     9  233     3       ZCN4-ZCU4  8     1     0   0.75     7   53428000   
1     9  138  None  ZC:BF H4-K4-N4  8  None  None   None  None       None   
2     9  007     2  ZC:BF U3-Z3-H4  8    16     1     45   195  181451000   
3     9  007     1       ZCU3-ZCH4  8    16     1     21     3  181451000   
4     9  007     2       ZCU3-ZCH4  8    16     1  21.25    10  181451000   
5     9  007     1       ZCU3-ZCH5  8    16     1  11.25     3  181451000   
6     9  007     2       ZCU3-ZCH5  8    16     1   11.5     2  181451000   
7     9  007     1       ZCU3-ZCK4  8    16     1   13.5     3  181451000   
8     9  007     2       ZCU3-ZCK4  8    16     1  13.75     8  181451000   
9     9  007     1       ZCU3-ZCN4  8    16     1      7     3  181451000   
10    9  007     2       ZCU3-ZCN4  8    16     1   7.25     8  181451000   
11    9  007     1       ZCU3-ZCU4  8    16     1  15.25     3  181451000   
12    9  007     2       ZCU3-ZCU4  8    16     1   15.5     1  181451000   
13    9  007     2       ZCU3-ZCU5  8    16     1  25.25     1  181451000   
14    9  007     1       ZCU3-ZCZ3  8    16     1     33     3  181451000   
15    9  007     2       ZCU3-ZCZ3  8    16     1  33.25    20  181451000   
16    9  007     2       ZCU3-ZCZ4  8    16     1   9.75     1  181451000   
17    9  007     2       ZCU3-ZCZ5  8    16     1  29.75     1  181451000   

   336       34   346 35      48   49                 52        75  \
0   ...      2   431875     3  X   19590  CME  20130715053428544  20130715   
1   ...   None     6613  None  f  164576  CME  20130714180206034  20130715   
2   ...      2  3177179  None  X    1647  CME  20130715181451830  20130715   
3   ...      2  3177179  None  X   21907  CME  20130715181451830  20130715   
4   ...      2  3177179  None  X   21907  CME  20130715181451830  20130715   
5   ...      2  3177179  None  X  504398  CME  20130715181451830  20130715   
6   ...      2  3177179  None  X  504398  CME  20130715181451830  20130715   
7   ...      2  3177179  None  X   21970  CME  20130715181451830  20130715   
8   ...      2  3177179  None  X   21970  CME  20130715181451830  20130715   
9   ...      2  3177179  None  X  558644  CME  20130715181451830  20130715   
10  ...      2  3177179  None  X  558644  CME  20130715181451830  20130715   
11  ...      2  3177179  None  X   22098  CME  20130715181451830  20130715   
12  ...      2  3177179  None  X   22098  CME  20130715181451830  20130715   
13  ...      2  3177179  None  X  504409  CME  20130715181451830  20130715   
14  ...      2  3177179  None  X  588275  CME  20130715181451830  20130715   
15  ...      2  3177179  None  X  588275  CME  20130715181451830  20130715   
16  ...      2  3177179  None  X  519645  CME  20130715181451830  20130715   
17  ...      2  3177179  None  X   19282  CME  20130715181451830  20130715   

        83     9  
0     1491   156  
1     None   104  
2   180151  1634  
3   118087  1634  
4   118088  1634  
5    29594  1634  
6    29595  1634  
7    50008  1634  
8    50009  1634  
9    48554  1634  
10   48555  1634  
11   52504  1634  
12   52505  1634  
13   16282  1634  
14  265779  1634  
15  265780  1634  
16   32899  1634  
17   20689  1634  

[18 rows x 24 columns]
```